# Problem exporting dataframe to excel sheets

Tags: r, xlsx, openxlsx, r-rio

I have been using the rio package to import / export data in r

currently, I cannot export to excel. Every time I try to export a file in .xlsx, it does not give any error messages but the generated file is always a small 22 bytes and does not open.

I tried to export using openxlsx package which also produces the same corrupted file.

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

This is an example code I tried:

```
xx = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(0,8,9,7,6))
rio::export(xx, "xx.xlsx")

 library(openxlsx)
 write.xlsx(xx, file = "xx.xlsx")
```

and this is my session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
```

Comment: `I tried to export using openxlsx package which generates the same error`. What is the error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, the posted code works as expected. The output files were 6.2 KB, vote to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @RonakShah I meant it also generates a corrupted file. I changed the question to clarify that. thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.

Comment: @RuiBarradas besides voting to close, was wondering if someone has any suggestions on where the problem can be. a dependency package? java? etc...

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for trying. I re installed rio and openxlsx packages but still without a resolution.

Comment: Package openxls does not depend on Java, it uses Rcpp. The error must be somewhere else. Try reinstalling Rcpp?

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for the suggestion. I also tried that. but the generated file is still corrupted. I am using a work laptop without admin rights but do not believe this is a reason.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and cannot think of anything relevant to WIndows, I'll retract my close vote. Good luck.

Comment: Same with me. the code works as expected the output file 6.1KB.